# Grayscale SVG in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there an option to convert colored charts to grayscale in Highcharts? Have a need to generate SVG that represents grayscaled image. A CSS based option wouldn't help as the SVG is not being used in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to define your own colors http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think converting to Grayscale image or creating one on Grayscale (Monochrome) would be different from defining colours. My understanding is that each color should be substituted with an equivalent shade of Gray. For a Chart handle provided, is there a way to convert into grayscale. A solution with CSS exists but I would like to get the SVG after grayscaling. http://jsfiddle.net/KDtAX/487/ (referred from http://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html)

Something on these lines would be helpful

chart.convert2GrayScale().getSVG()